# Read line by line of file error

Tags: c++

I have to parse data from file. The file has the following structure:

```
text1.txt 1
text2.txt 2
text3.txt 4
```

The file can download at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31cm60hqpyzdhxd/test.txt)
I want to get text1.txt and 1. So my code as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{ 
FILE    *fp= NULL;
int     status= -1;
char    name[100];
char *filename="test.txt";
fp= ::fopen(filename, "rt");
if (!fp)
    {
        printf("\Error open: \"%s\"\n\n", filename);
        return;
    }
do
{
int number=0;
status= fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name,number);

}
while (status!= EOF);
}
```

I am using C++. My problem is that it is crashed at

```
status= fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name,number);
```

The error is " Access violation writing location 0x00000000.". What is problem? Could you fix help me?

Comment: Read the manual of `fscanf`, are you sure the compiler didn't tell you any warnings?

Comment: What happens when the string entered is 100 or more characters?

Comment: No. Problem at %d at status= fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name,number);If I only use status= fscanf(fp, "%s", name), It is ok

Comment: This question only barely qualifies as C++; except for the `::` in `::fopen()`, it is a C program.

Comment: `status != EOF` should probably `status == 2` (unless you like reading junk)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there's a common subset of C and C++ , that subset is still a part of C++!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, but there's C++ and there's C compiled by a C++ compiler, and this is almost C compiled by a C++ compiler, except for the one (unnecessary) `::`.  To be legitimate C++, it should be `int main()` — unless Microsoft has carved out a non-standard exception for C++ programs.  It doesn't really matter; it was a mostly throwaway comment — and it is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass arguments to be scanned to `fscanf` by address :

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name, &number);
```

The compiler probably warned you :

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
```

Your code has undefined behavior, which is the source of your crash.

Comment: Is the cast to an `int*` actually undefined behavior?

Comment: fscanf will attempt to write at invalid address, which has undefined behavior. @user3677103 : On StackOverflow, remember to accept answers if they helped you.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I assumed that the implicit cast from an `int` to an `int*` was the undefined behavior that quantdev was referring to -- he cleared it up in his comment. Thanks, quantdev!

Comment: OK. There's no such thing as "implicit cast"; what's happening here (or what would be happening if it weren't explicity undefined behaviour) is an *alias*. The representation in memory of one object is being read as if it were the representation of an object of another type. Aliasing is different from conversion too.